# SQL issue - The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'sv2017'

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I keep receiving the error

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'sv2017'.
>
> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'sv2010'.

with the following script:

```
select 
    sv2017.id, sv2017.TotalArea, sv2017.uarn, 
    sv2010.id, sv2010.PlantMachineryValue, sv2017.PlantMachineryValue, 
    sv2010.uarn, sv2017.BAReferenceNumber 
from 
    (select * 
     from summaryvaluation sv 
     join SummaryValuationPlant svp on sv.id = svp.SummaryValuationId  
     where sv.yearid = 2 
       and sv.id in (select id /*Get the most recent valuation for the list year*/
                     from
                         (select 
                              id, uarn, 
                              rank() over (partition by uarn order by fromdate desc) as RankOrder 
                          from 
                              summaryvaluation 
                          where 
                              yearid = 2 and systemactive = 1) tbl
                     where 
                         rankorder = 1)) sv2017
left outer join 
    (select * 
     from summaryvaluation sv2 
     join SummaryValuationPlant svp2 on sv2.id = svp2.SummaryValuationId 
     where sv2.yearid = 1 
       and sv2.id in (select id /*Get the most recent valuation for the list year*/
                      from
                          (select 
                               id, uarn, 
                               rank() over (partition by uarn order by fromdate desc) as RankOrder 
                           from 
                               summaryvaluation 
                           where 
                               yearid = 1 and systemactive = 1) tbl
                      where 
                          rankorder = 1)) sv2010 on sv2017.uarn = sv2010.uarn
where
    isnull (sv2017.PlantMachineryValue, 0) > isnull(sv2010.PlantMachineryValue, 0)
```

and I can not see where I am going wrong! It is probably obvious and my brain is just not functioning but any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The error is very clear

Comment: This is just one reason why you shoudn't just "slap in" a `SELECT *`. Clearly both the tables `summaryvaluation` and `SummaryValuationPlant` have a column `id` and therefore `SELECT` (within the subqueries) will return the column `id` and the column `id`; you see the problem there?

Comment: Use aliases eg `T1.id As Foo, T2.id As Bar` SQL Server needs to know which `id` you're referring to

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably here:

```
select * 
     from summaryvaluation sv 
     join SummaryValuationPlant svp
```

That code appears in 2 different places (with different aliases). Regardless, I suspect both tables have an id column, so when you use this in a derived table, SQL doesn't know if you are referring to the one from the sv table or the svp table.

To correct this problem, remove the * and list just those columns you will be using elsewhere in the larger query.

Comment: You're welcome. Keep at it, and I'm sure your SQL skills will improve.